# can i load one action inside the div user in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, themes

i am beginner in cakephp and i need simple template in cakephp .
i have simple code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title><?php echo $title_for_layout?></title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!-- Include external files and scripts here (See HTML helper for more info.) -->
<?php echo $scripts_for_layout ?>
</head>
<body>
<!-- If you'd like some sort of menu to
show up on all of your views, include it here -->
<div id="header">
<div id="menu">...</div>
</div>
<!-- Here's where I want my views to be displayed -->
<?php echo $content_for_layout ?>

<!-- Add a footer to each displayed page -->
<div id="footer">...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but this template is simple ,
***for example***
i have users_controller and view , add , delete and index view .
i want load user action in User div in this image.

[image]

Comment: It is not really clear to me what your question is. If you need a HTML layout that is not Cake specific. PHP is a simple template itself. Call $this->set("foo", "bar") in the controller, and make <?php echo $foo ?> in the view. One should not put any logic into views anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a fully rendered view or data from anywhere in Cake using **$this->requestAction->();**

More info available in the [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/view/991/requestAction).